# how to onclick work on data table bootstrap

Tags: php, onclick

i have start hyperlink like this :

```
"action"=>"<a href='proses_hapus.php?id=$row[id_pemesanan]' )' class='btn btn-danger'><span onclick='return confirm(Are you sure ?)' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>"
```

that onclick is not work when i see inspect element. the code just show

```
onclick="return confirm(Are you sure ?)"
```

if i make onclick like this `onclick='('Are u sure ?')"`, inspect element will show `onclick="return confirm(" are="" you="" sure="" ?')'="">`

My question is how can i make `onclick="return confirm('Are u sure ?')"`. it should be write like that in inspect element. cz i have edit manual and its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this problem

```
"<a href='#' onclick='return confirm(`Are u sure ?`)'> link </a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, your question, or string value, should be in string quotes, like this:

```
<a href="proses_hapus.php?id=$row[id_pemesanan]')" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Link</a>
```

You can also try a more advanced way of doing it.

### Advanced event handling

But normally you would like to [separate your HTML and Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_and_JavaScript), so I suggest you don't use inline event handlers, but put a class on your link and add an event listener to it.

```
<a href="proses_hapus.php?id=$row[id_pemesanan]')" class="confirmation">Link</a>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
    };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
</script>
```

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/TgjL7/) will only work in modern browsers (for older IEs you can use `attachEvent()`, `returnValue` and provide an implementation for `getElementsByClassName()` or use a library like jQuery that will help with cross-browser issues). You can read more about [this advanced event handling method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: hmm.. i cant use `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"` when i start `"<a href='#' nclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> </a>"` impossible to have " in same code

Comment: yea.. my data table-bootstrap will not show. its error.

Comment: i got the solution.. use ` that simbol